# Image breaking Flexbox grid

Tags: css, flexbox

I wanted to create a flex grid as follows:

```
-------------------------------
| Menu |     Header Image     |
|      |-----------------------
|      |     Content          |
-------------------------------
```

So I have this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  flex-basis: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header,
.content {
  width: 75%;
  flex-basis: 40%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And the html:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav id="menu">
      ...
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="/images/site/logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Content Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The layout works great without an image, but with an image, even if it's small, it puts the `Content` item next to the `Header Image`:

```
-----------------------------------------
| Menu |     Header Image     | Content |
|      |---------------------------------
|      |
-------
```

I tried:

```
.logo img {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  max-width:  80%;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

If I tweak `max-width` to `20%`, then the layout is fine. The image is not that wide, or tall, and hence am confused why it has to be shrunk so small for it to work.

Comment: you want to arrange things horizontally and vertically at the same time, I think CSS Grid is a better fit in your case instead of flex box

Comment: You should use css grid for this. Inside each grid area can use flex, but the layout should use grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, it's better to use `grid` for this layout.
But it is possible to do it with flex,
It is best to think of flex as a way of styling one row (or one column) of a div

You need to handle one "row" with a few "columns" in Flex to achieve what you want
When you were trying to have two columns, your mistake was that you used three siblings under the container
There should only be two sibling elements within the *container* (the flex element).

so you need to have

```
    <div class="flex-parent">
      <div class="col1"></div>
      <div class="col2"></div>
    </div>
```

for your example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav id="menu">
      ...
    </nav>
  </div> 
  <div class="content-and-header-wrapper"> // added this div
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="/images/site/logo.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <p>Content Here</p>
    </div>
  <div>

</div>
```

```
 col-1         col-2
-------------------------------
| Menu |     Header Image     |
|      |-----------------------
|      |     Content          |
-------------------------------
```

now the col-2 should be `flex` with `flex-direction: column;`
with 2 divs inside (one col with 2 rows ...)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column'>
      <div>
        Column One
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div>
        <img src="">
      </div>
       <div>
       Column Two
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I should use grid for this you are right - so grid is for a combo of rows and columns, whereas flexbox is either rows or columns (without hackery)?

Comment: I think that there is not only one right way to implement.
but yes, it seems that it is better to use 'grid' for a few rows/column layers, and flex is for one layer.